# Can I block internet access of a single app with firewalld?

Tags: linux, networking, opensuse, firewalld, appimage

Is it possible to prevent a single app to access the internet with firewalld?

To be precise, i have an application packaged as an AppImage, currently installed in my Home directory, and I want it to be blocked internet access.

The firewalld GUI only let me configure IP's, MAC's, services, and so on, but I can't find a way to manage single applications. Is it even possbile at all?

It if matters, I'm using openSUSE.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC no - even services are basically rules based on ports - it's literally an [XML file](https://firewalld.org/documentation/service/examples.html). As such, it's a *little* trickier, but not very much so.

You could use netstat or other means to work out what ports the application uses.

`netstat -p | grep program` would be a simple example of this.

Then write your own unit for the application to block the ports.

As far as I understand, firewalld isn't application based, it's just a front end for the port based firewall, with a few nice addons like zones.

You *might* be able to do this with something like SElinux or Apparmour instead, though naturally it's a different route from what you're trying.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this workaround and do more research.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do so?

A software called firejail(available in the Ubuntu repository) can block internet access for appimage programs.
Use the following code:

```
firejail --appimage --noprofile path/to/appimage
```